# Why (Hacker earth - Charged up Array) one code is accepted and another is producing wrong answer

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am trying to solve the Charged Up Array problem from the online judge Hacker Earth.
https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/arrays/1-d/practice-problems/algorithm/charged-up-array-f35a5e23/
I came up with the solution and written almost the same two different codes for the problem
The first one is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int T, n, i;
    long long int subset_Containg_Ai, x, sum;
    scanf("%d", &T);
    while(T--)
    {
            sum = 0;
            scanf("%d", &n);
            //subset_Containg_Ai = (long long int)pow(2, (n-1));
            //printf("Subset = %d\n", subset_Containg_Ai);
            for(i=0; i<n; i++)
            {
                scanf("%lld", &x);
                if(x>= pow(2, (n-1)))
                {
                    sum = (sum + x ) % 1000000007;
                }
            }

            printf("%lld\n", sum);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code is accepted in the judge server.
But here is another version of my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int T, n, i;
    long long int subset_Containg_Ai, x, sum;
    scanf("%d", &T);
    while(T--)
    {
            sum = 0;
            scanf("%d", &n);
            subset_Containg_Ai = (long long int)pow(2, (n-1));
            //printf("Subset = %d\n", subset_Containg_Ai);
            for(i=0; i<n; i++)
            {
                scanf("%lld", &x);
                if(x>=subset_Containg_Ai)
                {
                    sum = (sum + x ) % 1000000007;
                }
            }

            printf("%lld\n", sum);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**In the second code, I used an extra variable "subset_Containg_Ai" and using it to compare with the variable "x" instead of calling the function pow every time**. I thought it would increase the efficiency of the code. On the contrary, this second code is showing "Wrong Answer" by the judge! Can anyone tell me what is going on here?

Comment: don't compare floating point numbers via `=` (as part of `>=`). `pow` is for floating point numbers, not for integers

Comment: (though for powers of 2 that shouldnt be an issue)

Comment: 2^n-1 will exceed long long int range.

Comment: That's what you get for using casts to silence warnings instead of fixing the code, btw. Apart from that, your question boils down to "When is `(long long int)x` and `x` not the same?", which should be relatively obvious now.

Comment: @starboy_b could you please explain if 2^n-1 is exceeding the long long int range, how can it compare in the first code with "x" as "x" is a long long int too.

Comment: If `pow(2, n-1)` exceeds the value that can be stored in a `long long int`, then converting it to `long long int` will give undefined behaviour.   If `long long int` is 64 bits, overflow will occur for `n > 63`  (allowing for the sign bit).   That doesn't occur in your first code, since that will convert `x` to `double` and compare that with `pow(2,n-1)`.    (Whether that is correct, depends on criteria of the online judge).

Comment: @JanezKuhar in each subset every element is either in or not, that makes `2^n`. If you either exclude the empty subset or the subset that equals the array you end up with `2^n -1`

Comment: Constraints: *1 ≤ N ≤ 100000*. Now will `pow(2, 99999)` fit in `long long`? Hmmm...

Comment: @JanezKuhar if all subset contain i-th element then only (n-1) elements can be in or not resulting in 2^(n-1) number of subsets. Why is it so puzzling? When `2^n` is number of subsets with `n` elements then `2^(n-1)` is the same quantity for `n-1` elements

Comment: I guess the correct formula for K_i should be: `(2^(n)-1) - (2^(n-1) - 1) = 2^n - 2^(n-1) = 2^n - 2^n * 2^(-1) = 2^n(1 - 1/2) = 2^n / 2 = 2^(n-1)` Ah, now it all makes sense! ^^